# Условие where в with параметре

Tags: yii2

C помощью activeRecord хочу добиться следующее.

Есть Номенклатуры, у них есть мероприятия.

Например:
Номенклатура Волейбол, и в ней 3 мероприятия
Номенклатура Футбол и в ней 6 мероприятий.

Мне нужно подгрузить номенклатуры и жадно к ним подгрузить мероприятия. 
Делаю след.:

```
Nom::find()->with('event')->all();
```

Но в списке попадаются номенклатуры, внутри которых нет ни одного активного мероприятия, такие не нужны. Исключаю их.

```
Nom::find()->joinWith('event')
        ->where(['event.is_active'=>1])
        ->all();
```

Теперь номенклатуры, у которых нет активных мероприятий не выбираются. Но есть Номенклатуры, в которых содержатся неактивные мероприятия. Такие мероприятия выводить не нужно.

Нужно как-то включить условие Where (is_active=>1) также для таблицы Event. 
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно это сделать прямо в связи моделей

```
public function getEvent()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Event::class, ['id_чего-то' => 'id')->where([/* тут условие */]);
}
```

Можно присвоить псевдоним таблице и добавить условие так, как Вы делаете.

```
->with('event')
->joinWith(
  'event' => function(ActieQuery $query)
  {
    $query->from(['event' => Event::tableName()]); // назначается псевдоним таблицы
  }
)
->where(['event.active' => 1])
```